# jquery load event never triggered

Tags: jquery

I am attempting to understand the 'load' event in jQuery as described here: http://api.jquery.com/load-event/.  So far, I have been unable to get it triggered even once!

Here is some sample code.  The only console message that turns up is "DOM READY"  -not a single load call.  Replacing calls to .load() with .bind('load',..)  does not make any difference.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
          <script src="lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script>
           $(function(){
              console.log("DOM READY");
           });
           $(document).load(function(){
              console.log("Document Loaded");
           });
           $('#foo').load(function(){
              console.log("foo loaded");
           });
           $('#bar img').load(function(){
              console.log('image loaded');
           });
           $('#bar').load(function(){
              console.log('bar loaded');
           });
           </script>
   </head>
   <body>
     <div id="foo">Hellow world</div>
     <div id="bar">
        <img src="pics/pig.png"/>
     </div>
   </body>
   </html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @j08691 It worked for the OP as well, *The only console message that turns up is "DOM READY"*.

Comment: to even access `$("#foo")` it would already have to be "loaded"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the document.ready event to do your bindings, you are guaranteed that elements exist:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#foo').load(function(){console.log("foo loaded");});
}
```

Comment: Great answer - I plugged it in and saw the rest of my problem (div is not associated with a url as Jonathan pointed out).  Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

You cannot bind to items that don't yet exist. For instance, when you do the following:

```
$('#foo').load(function(){
    console.log("foo loaded");
});
```

The `#foo` item doesn't exist, so you cannot bind to its load event. Note also what the documentation has to say of the `.load` event itself:

> *This event can be sent to any element associated with a URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the window object.*

Your div elements don't "load".

Comment: But why doesn't `$(function(){}` work then? that's the shorthand-notation of `$(document).ready();`

Comment: @11684 It does. The OP said *The only console message that turns up is "DOM READY"*.

Comment: Oops, misread... That's strange, last time I tried that it didn't work @JonathanSampson

Comment: You are right.  Placing everything inside of the top $(function()) makes all the issues self-evident.  It is, however, unfortunate that $('#bar').load() is not triggered after img is loaded.  This means, no "loaded all children" event for us.  :-(

Answer (score 0):

Exactly as Jonathan said. If you want an example I suggest to look at the documentation in this website: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

It has very good references plus I understand by your example that you want to keep it simple so that's what you will find here

Answer (score 0):

I tried reproducing your example and as stated by others only the DOM READ one fired.

I also modified the script and tried getting load to work on img, a, div and script element. None fired.

I also tried passing in the window object (after all this a 'window' event. This did work.

My conclusion is that despite the jquery documentation, it only works with the window object:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    alert("window loaded");
 });
```

I only tested in chrome and only tested the elements I mentioned. I personally would just use the document.ready functionality. According to the documentation .load with images doesn't work very well anyways. Lots of caveats with this particular function: